# Is $M_g$ a subvariety of $M_{h}$ for some $h>g$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $g\geq 24$. Then $M_g$ is of general type. Does there exist $h>g$ such that $M_g$ is a subvariety of $M_h$? That is, does there exist an immersion $M_g \to M_g$?

If the answer is not known, then what would one expect?

Comment: Do you have a candidate map?

Comment: No, but maybe something like Knudsen clutching can be used?